# Finding difference in dates using SQL values as PHP variables and strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to determine how many days overdue a dvd is. My code is:

```
$query = "SELECT rental_date FROM rented_dvds WHERE dvd_id = '$dvd_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $result);
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("$newDate");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("NOW");
$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);
```

rented_dvds is captured when the DVD is rented using NOW(). When I run that code I get: "Warning: DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in .../.../return_dvd.php on line 34"

Line 34 is the line that starts with the $newDate variable.

This is all code that I've cobbled together from different sources, but I thought I had cobbled properly. I've been searching for an answer, and have tried a few different solutions, but I can't seem to make any of them work.

Also, this is my first post, so 'hi!' and thanks for any help!

Comment: `$result` isn't a date or a string. If the query executed successfully, `$result` is a **mysqli_result** object. (If the query encountered an error, $result will just be FALSE.) With the **mysqli_result** object, you will want to call one of its functions, like `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to retrieve a row. (If there are no more rows to fetch, it will return FALSE instead of a row). The value you are looking for will be an element in the row (associative array) returned by `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Who rents dvds these days?! :)

Comment: You can probably even do the calculations in mysql, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff. @spencer7593 is right though with your current implementation. Also `strtotime("NOW")` is probably == to `time()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you fetching in the right way ?because you are directly fetch $result which is give you in an pbject or array form ..you have to write

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $row['rental_date']);
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what I was doing there!

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because $result is in fact an object that can contain multiple rows. You have to walk trough it to retain the particular row you need :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT rental_date FROM rented_dvds WHERE dvd_id = '$dvd_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $row['rental_date']);
$startTimeStamp = strtotime("$newDate");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("NOW");
$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);

?>
```